# MVC with Entity Framework Model Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

I'm having trouble mapping my models:

**User to Admin 1 to 0..1 relationship:**

One user can be one kind of admin status or no admin status

**Users to Tickets 1 to Many relationship:**

Users can open multiple tickets but a ticket can only be assigned to one User. User to Ticket 1 to Many

**Administrator to Ticket 1 to Many relationship:**

Admin (A user with admin status) has tickets assigned to him to fix. The ticket should have an adminID to identify which admin is assigned to it .

I followed tutorials which already has models (LOOK BELOW). It's my first time creating a MVC with Entity Framework Web Application so I don't know if Circular Mapping is possible.

I get this error:

> "FK_dbo.User_dbo.Administrator_AdministratorID". The conflict occurred
>   in database "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext",
>   table "dbo.Administrator", column 'AdministratorID'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

    [Column("FirstName")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
    }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public int? AdministratorID { get; set; }
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
    public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Administrator.cs

```
public class Administrator
{
    public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
    public string AdministratorTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

}
```

Ticket.cs

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }     
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I followed this 1 to 0..1 model for my (User/Instructor) 1 to 0...1 (Administrator/OfficeAssignment)

```
public class Instructor
{
    public Int InstructorID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public int? OfficeAssignmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }

    public int? HomeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Home Home { get; set; }

}

public class OfficeAssignment
{
    public int OfficeAssignmentID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

}
```

I followed this 1 to many model for my (Administrator/Team) 1 to 0...1 (Ticket/Player)

Player.cs

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; } // This is new
}
```

Team.cs

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime Founded { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<player> Players { get; set; } // This is new
}
```

Comment: You are missing  public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; } on your Ticket model. Also make sure to define [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]

Comment: I added `public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; } ` to the ticket model and `[ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]` above `public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }` in User.cs and Ticket.cs and it still had the same error

Comment: @UthmanRahimi `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.User_dbo.Administrator_AdministratorID". The conflict occurred in database "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext", table "dbo.Administrator", column 'AdministratorID'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: Have you verified if the AdministratorID has a valid value and is existing on your Administrator table records?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I found the problem! I didn't decalre my administrator in my Configuration file before assign AdminID in my User part.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I didn't decalre my administrator in my Configuration file before assigning AdminID in my User declaration.

Configuration.cs Snippet

```
        var administrator = new List<Administrator>
        {
            new Administrator {AdministratorID = 1, AdministratorTitle = "Administrator Lvl 1"},
            new Administrator {AdministratorID = 1, AdministratorTitle = "Administrator Lvl 2"},
            new Administrator {AdministratorID = 1, AdministratorTitle = "Administrator Lvl 3"},

        };
        administrator.ForEach(s => context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(p => p.AdministratorID, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var users = new List<User>
    {
        new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1,AdministratorID = 1},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1,AdministratorID = 2},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1 ,DepotID = 1,AdministratorID = 3},
        new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},

    };


        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.FirstMidName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```